# Is Clang-3.3 not available for Sierra and future releases?

Tags: llvm-clang, macos-sierra

I have tried to upgrade my macports after upgrading my iMac to Sierra. When Clang-3.3 was encountered, **port upgrade** gave the message:
*llvm-3.3 is not supported on macOS Sierra or newer*
and stopped further upgrade process.

Had Macports stopped producing Clang-3.3 (and its dependents) for Sierra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this ticket](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/52206), and the Portfiles of [llvm-3.6](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/lang/llvm-3.6/Portfile) and earlier, I would conclude that you'll need at least `llvm-3.7` if you want it to install on Sierra.